# Swift back button with segue show not showing

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

So I tried everything with showing up the back button but it just won't work

[image]
This is how i arrange my View Controllers Used segue show from view controller to site view controller

[image]
And here is the site view controller that isn't showing back button
I even tried adding NavigationBar and a button with this function

```
self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Also failed

Update:
I tried this in both view controllers it's returning nil
in viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear

```
print(self.navigationController?.restorationIdentifier)
```

Comment: select SiteViewController and XCODE->Editor->EmbedIn->NavigationController. then will appear back button

Answer (score 0):

Once I got the same problem, when I was try to use `view` property of my `UIViewController` before it loaded properly. This caused problems with loading my navigation bar items. In fact, you should not touch `view` property until `viewDidLoad` method is called. Check, maybe it is your case, maybe you use `view` property in `prepareForSegue` method or in observers?

Comment: if (segue.identifier == "siteSegue"){
            let destview = segue.destinationViewController as! SiteViewController;
            destview.gg = sender as! NSDictionary
        }

Comment: @MuaathAli do `gg` property have willSet or didSet observers?

Comment: well i tried removing the properties and still the back button doesnt appear

Comment: @MuaathAli How do you show Site vc? You should use `performSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)` or `navigationController?.pushViewController(_:animated:)`. If this is not the point, then I need more information; can you share your project?

Comment: in the prepareForSegue I'm using this to pass

'if (segue.identifier == "siteSegue"){
            let destview = segue.destinationViewController as! SiteViewController;
            destview.gg = sender as! NSDictionary
        }'

maybe it has something to do with it?